# Add a datatable to a data set

Tags: c#-2.0

Hii...

I have a data table 'dt1' that is belongs to 'ds1'. I have created another instance of dataset 'ds2' and try to add the datatable 'dt1' to 'ds2'. Now i got one exception 'DataTable already belongs to another data set'. Is there any reliable way to add the dt1 to ds2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it would be

```
DataSet.Tables[0].Copy()
```